# C# MVC5 BulkData Insert doesn't work on partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a problem with inserting bulk data from partial view in MVC5. It works completely fine when its not a partial view. I am using this example: http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/08/how-to-insert-multiple-record-to-database-at-a-time-aspnet-mvc4.html
This is the original code from the controller:

```
public ActionResult BulkData()
    {
            // This is only for show by default one row for insert data to the database
            List<ContactInfo> ci = new List<ContactInfo> {new ContactInfo{ ID = 0, ContactName = "", ContactNo=""} };
            return View(ci);
    }
```

I change it to(because I want to use the functionality in bootrap modal popup):

```
public ActionResult BulkData()
    {
            // This is only for show by default one row for insert data to the database
            List<ContactInfo> ci = new List<ContactInfo> {new ContactInfo{ ID = 0, ContactName = "", ContactNo=""} };
            return PartialView(ci);
    }
```

After changes it doesn't work. I can't understand why. I also added all scripts from layout to partial view, but it also didn't help. This is the code from the view:

```
@model List<MVCBulkInsert.ContactInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Insert Bulk Data";
}
<style>
    th {
        text-align:left;
    }
    td {
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("BulkData","Save", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px green">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }

        <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add New</a></div>
        <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
               <th>Contact Name</th>
                <th>Contact No</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a[j].ContactName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a[j].ContactNo)</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (j > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
    }
</div>

@* Here I will add Jquery Code for validation / dynamically add new rows / Remove rows etc *@

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //1. Add new row
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
                var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
                var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

                var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>');
                $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                    // Replaced Name
                    var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                    var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                    $(this).attr('name', newN);
                    //Replaced value
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                        $(this).attr('value', '');
                    }

                    // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                    $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

                });
                $trLast.after($trNew);

                // Re-assign Validation 
                var form = $("form")
                    .removeData("validator")
                    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            });

            // 2. Remove 
            $('a.remove').live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Please specify what "doesn't work" means. Did you debug? Did you see an Exception?

Comment: There's no exception. Somehow the the javascript doesn't work because even the link in the view `<div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add New</a></div>` doesn't add new row to the table

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that partial views don't recognize scripts sections.